# Python os.makedirs непонятное поведение

Tags: python, файлы, ос

Не могу понять что не так в этом коде, os.makedirs создает 1 папку, а 2ую отказывается по не понятной мне причине, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
import os

class Newclass :
    intstring = 1;
    def mainfunc(self, a, b):
        print(a)
        print(b)
        if os.path.exists(a) and os.path.exists(b): 
            print ("OK...")
        else: 
            print ("Creating Dirs...")
            if os.makedirs(a) and os.makedirs(b):
                print ("MakeDirs - OK")
            else:
                print ("MakeDirs - Error")





A = Newclass()
A.mainfunc("/home/pc/1", "/home/pc/2")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.makedirs` возвращает `None` в случае успеха (в случае ошибки вызывает исключение), поэтому второй вызов в `if os.makedirs(a) and os.makedirs(b):` уже не происходит и директория `/home/pc/2` не создается.